# JExcelAPI - writing date to Excel sheet ignores day, month and year

Tags: java, excel, datetime, jexcelapi

I try to generate some Excel sheets in Java application using JExcelAPI (v. 2.6.3) and can't generate date cells properly. For example, for code:

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = null;
    workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\tmp\\tests.xls"));
    try {
        Date date = new Date();
        final WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet", 0);
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(0, 0, date);
        sheet.addCell(dateTime);
        System.out.println("Date1 is " + date);
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2007);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        date = cal.getTime();
        dateTime = new DateTime(0, 1, date);
        sheet.addCell(dateTime);
        System.out.println("My birthday is on " + date);
    } finally {
        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
    }
```

The output (on console) is:
*Date1 is Mon Jun 08 11:14:45 GMT+01:00 2009

My birthday is on Wed Oct 17 08:15:45 GMT+01:00 2007*

And in Excel file the cells are
*1900-01-00  10:14:46

1900-01-00  07:15:46*

The time part in Excel is corrected to UTC and the date part is discarded. While the reference mentions time zone problem, it says nothing about discarding dates. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK. I figured it. Creating DateFormat

```
DateFormat customDateFormat = new DateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
WritableCellFormat dateFormat = new WritableCellFormat (customDateFormat);
```

and passing it to DateTime constructor

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(0, 0, date, dateFormat);
```

fixes it. It seems that by default only time part is taken. Sorry for my dumbness.

Comment: Don't add a new answer.  Edit your original.

Comment: or accept this answer to make it clear you figured out the problem

Comment: Solved my problem to :-) Only thing I was doing different was I created the DateTime like 'new DateTime(0, 0, date)' so without the format. I afterwards added the format using the setCellFormat(..) function on the DateTime object. But that didn't work, passing it in via the constructor did. Thanks for this very helpful tip! :-)

Answer (score 0):

POI is not the answer I'd recommend.  JExcel can manage it.  I don't see where you've set the type on that cell.  Have a look at [DateFormats](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6/docs/index.html).

The problem is the same if you're using Excel.  If you enter a Date into a cell that doesn't have that format set you'll have unexpected behavior.

Comment: I created a WritableCell of type jxl.write.DateTime. I expected it to set the proper type (as jxl.write.Number sets type to number). But it seems that a DateFormat is also needed. I thought it only controlled display but it also affects which part of java.util.Date is written.